# Gnome-Shell, use the hot corner to display Application

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm currently tweaking my new Gnome-Shell inside a VM before doing it on my current laptop and I would like to know how to display the application drawer when the mouse go on the hot corner instead of the running applications.

The best would be to display the application drawer from the hot corner and keep the running app with the Windows key.

Anybody ever tried to do that ? I think that I need to modify some `.js` file inside `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/`, but I did not figured out how.

Edit : I am able to remove the "frequently used app" tab (from `appDrawer.js`), but I can't use the "All apps" tab as the main view of the hot corner.